# ctype loaded shared library symbol also defined in glibc; how to choose symbol?

Tags: linker, segmentation-fault, shared-libraries, ctypes, glibc

Using python ctypes; a loaded shared library (A) defines a `sem_init` function that is called by a subsequent loaded shared library (B), which is linked to library A. Execution (in gdb) results in a segmentation fault where it looks like that library B calls `sem_init@@GLIBC_2.4` from `/lib/libpthread.so.0` (part of glibc?) instead of `sem_init` provided by library A.

To confirm, I renamed `sem_init` in library A and B, and the problem goes away. Unfortunately, other programs depend on the symbol `sem_init` in library A so this cannot be a solution. How do I make sure library B calls `sem_init` from library A without any changes to library A?

Comment: What command lines are used to build the 2 libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unfortunately, other programs depend on the symbol sem_init in library A so this cannot be a solution.

The reference from `libB` to `sem_init` resolves to the definition inside `libpthread.so.0` (part of GLIBC) because `libpthread.so.0` is loaded as a dependency of the main `python` binary, and thus appears *before* `libA` in the symbol search list. So every "normal" reference to `sem_init` will resolve to `libpthread`s definition. This is working as intended (it's a really bad idea (TM) to override symbols provided by the standard library).

You could force `libB.so` to use `libA.so:sem_init` by doing something like this in `libB` (error checking omitted):

```
void *h = dlopen("libA.so", RTLD_NOW|RTLD_GLOBAL)
void (*p_sem_init)(...) = dlsym(h, "sem_init");

// Call it:
p_sem_init(...);
```

This would work *IF* `sem_init` is the only conflicting symbol, but is likely to break in non-obvious ways if there are other symbol conflicts.